# Python function

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I have this function:

```
def check_if_year(years):
    if years.isnumeric():
        year = int(years)
```

How would I recall year in that function to use it outside of the function and into another function? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You should recall that function using return

```
def check_if_year(years):
    if years.isnumeric():
        year = int(years)
        return year
```

This returns/recalls year

Comment: If years might be multiple years in, say, a list, he could be looking to use yield and a generator.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann but his want is to only use year outside the function say as a variable etc..

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_if_year(years):
    if years.isnumeric():
        year = int(years)
        return year
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `return` from the function:

```
def check_if_year(years):
    if years.isnumeric():
        return int(years)
```

You can then assign `year` as:

```
year = check_if_year(somestring)
```

outside that function.

Comment: try:
    file_name_one = input("First file name: ")
    file_stream = open(file_name_one, "r")
    for line in file_stream:
        year_str = line[:4]
        years = year_str
        check_if_year(years)
        year = check_if_year(years)
        check_leap_year(year)

i get an attribute error

Comment: so i did year = check_if_year(years) then 
check_leap_year(year) which is my second function but i get an attribute error

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the full traceback - is `check_leap_year` also assuming `year` will be a string? E.g. do you call `isdigit()` again?

Answer (score 0):

You can return the value of year as input to another funcion.

```
def check_if_year(years):
    if years.isnumeric():
        year = int(years)
        return year # function returns year 

y = check_if_year(years) # Call the check_if_year function and store the result in y

another_function(y) # Pass the return value year to another function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose that [EAFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Exceptions) is more Pythonic than the [LBYL](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl) approach you have:

```
def check_if_year(years):
    try:
        return int(years)
    except ValueError as e:
        print e
        # do something with the fact you have a bad date...
```

Interact this way:

```
>>> check_if_year('1999')
1999
>>> check_if_year('abc')
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
```

Then if you wanted to 'put inside another function' you could do something like this:

```
def leap_year(st):
    def check_if_year(year):
        try:
            return int(year)
        except ValueError as e:
            raise

    n=check_if_year(st)
    if n % 400 == 0:
        return True
    if n % 100 == 0:
        return False
    if n % 4 == 0:
        return True
    # else    
    return False        

print leap_year('1900')        # False
print leap_year('2000')        # True
print leap_year('next year')   # exception
```

Comment: your except clause is worse than useless.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers That is kinda harsh. It is just an ignored `except` clause. (Or at least one that only prints the exception as an example.) Who says that an except needs to do anything? It is a simple example to show the OP an alternate way to code a simple function. What would YOU have the except do in this case? It is up to the OP what is to be done with a bad year string.

Comment: "Errors should never pass silently." (Zen of Python) - and I've lost _days_ debugging bad code that silently swallowed exceptions or assumed too much about what went wrong exactly. Remember that your answer will be read by a lot of newcomers that may understand it as being a good practice - which it's not. wrt/ "What would I do", it really depends on the context - either let the exception propagate, wrap it into another more specific exception, or something more complex (like in the case of a HTTP form validation), but I would certainly not just print the exception and call it a day.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: This is not meant to be production code. It is a simple example of `try/except` that the OP can choose to learn more about or not. Since what is to be done with a bad year string is not specified in the original, it makes no sense to specify it here. The second example I added (based on the OP's comments) does exactly what you say it should: die on a bad string.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remember_year( year ): # Return a function that 'remembers' the value of year
    return lambda x: x + year

plus10 = remember_year( 10 )
print plus10( 5 )
>> 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is actually mostly useless - what are you going to do if `year` is not numeric anyway ?

The simplest solution is to just try to build an `int` from whatever `year` is and handle the exception (how you want to handle it depends on the context) :

```
try:
    year = int(year)
except ValueError as e:
    handle_the_problem_one_way_or_another(year, e)
else:
    call_some_other_func(year)
```